# PHP-FPM won't start on Docker using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a very strange issue here, and i am not sure what i am doing wrong, must be something simple but i just cannot figure it out.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aaa
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=aaa
    - MYSQL_USER=aaa
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=aaa
    - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    - MYSQL_HOST=localhost

php-fpm:
  build: .
  dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
  container_name: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../app:/var/www/html
  links:
    - mysql
  environment: 
    PHP_php5enmod: 'bcmath gd gmp intl mbstring mysql mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql redis zip sockets'

caddy:
  build: .
  dockerfile: caddy/Dockerfile
  container_name: caddy
  volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www/html
      - ./caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
      - ./caddy/certs:/root/.caddy
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "443:443"
  links:
   - mysql
   - php-fpm
```

The Dockerfile for php-fpm:

```
FROM alterway/php:7.1-fpm

# update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash zip unzip

# require the asset plugin
RUN composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1"

# copy the entrypoint
COPY ./php-fpm/docker-entrypoint.sh /root/docker-entrypoint.sh

# setup permissions
RUN chmod +x /root/docker-entrypoint.sh

# Clean up, try to reduce image size (much as you can on Debian..)
RUN apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/doc /usr/share/man /usr/share/locale

ENTRYPOINT ["/root/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

( if i comment out the ENTRYPOINT the container starts just fine )

And in my docker-entrypoint.sh file, i am just trying to run a migration:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run the migration
/var/www/html/yii migrate/up --interactive=0 --migrationPath=/var/www/html/vendor/twisted1919/yii2-options/migrations
```

So all i want to do is to run a shell script right after the container starts, but nothing seems to work.

Another thing, if i comment out the ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile, while the container starts and executes the database migration, it complaints it does not find a valid mysql driver, but if i login in the container and try to run the migration manually, then it works just fine, so maybe something is wrong with `alterway/docker-php`

Comment: I think the issue here is that MYSQL is not ready to accept connections when the php-fpm container tries to run the migrations. I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was indeed the fact mysql was not ready for connections. I didn't went for a health check thing, i simply wrapped all in a shell script to start/stop/restart docker-compose and also to call the scripts i need inside the container, it's way easier this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a [health check](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck) may help you out.

This way you can tell `docker-compose` to wait for mysql to be healthy before starting php-fpm